# Nesting multiple Stacknavigations in react-native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

i'am writing an expo (react-native) application using typescript and functional components. I have a very nesting stack navigation.

```
App: {
  NavigationConatainer: {
    DrawerNavigation: {
      StackNavigator1: {
        HomeScreen,
        DetailedScreen,
        ButtonTabNavigator: {
          InfoScreen,
          StackNavigation2: {
            MainScreen,
            SubScreen1,
            SubScreen2,
          },
          MetaScreen
        }
      }
    },
    SomeCustomDrawerItems,
  }
}
```

I hope this show the architecture a bit.

Now i got to problems.

1. the SubScreen1 is above the ButtonTabNavigation Tab
2. How i can hide the header from StackNavigation1 on SubScreen1 and 2 and show the new StackNavigation2 header

It seem to be the stack are mixed. Pressing the back button on SubScreen1 navigates to DetailedScreen from StackNavigation1.

Anybody who know's how to implement such nesting stacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like you to please try out this navigation structure and let me know if you face any issues.

creating the navigator objects (Drawer, Bottom tab & Stack)

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const Stack1 = createStackNavigator()
const Stack2 = createStackNavigator()
```

Creating functional components for each navigator:

```
const stack_1 = () => {
 return (
    <Stack1.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false, headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Stack1.Screen
        name={"home screen"}
        component={} //provide the home screen component here
      />
      <Stack1.Screen
        name={"detailed screen"}
        component={} //provide the detailed screen component here
      />
      <Stack1.Screen
        name={"bottom tab"}
        component={<bottom_tab />} //provide the bottom_tab component here
      />
    </Stack1.Navigator>
  )
}

const stack_2 = () => {
 return (
    <Stack2.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false, headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Stack2.Screen
        name={"MainScreen"}
        component={} //provide the main screen component here
      />
      <Stack2.Screen
        name={"SubScreen1"}
        component={} //provide the sub screen 1 component here
      />
      <Stack2.Screen
        name={"SubScreen2"}
        component={} //provide the sub screen 2 component here
      />
    </Stack2.Navigator>
  )
}

const bottom_tab = () => {
 return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false, headerShown: false }}
    >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={"InfoScreen"}
        component={} //provide the Info screen component here
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name={"nested stack 2"}
        component={<stack_2/>} //providing the stack_2 component here
      />     
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Using this structure, we have avoided your 1st problem. The subscreen1 & subscreen1 will have the bottom tab navigator visible.

Coming to your 2nd problem, using the `headerShown` option as **false**, we have *prevented the header of any stack to be visible in any of the screens*.

I would suggest you to create your own header as a component and call it in any screen, as this method gives you more flexibility over the existing header in terms of customization.
Basically, you can play around with it and in this case, avoid confusion.

Creating the header component:

```
const Header = () => 
    <View style={styles.nav_container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        <Feather
            name={'arrow-left'}
            size={moderateScale(30)}
            color={colors.white}
            style={{ marginRight: moderateScale(20) }}
         />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.nav_text}>Your Screen name</Text>
    </View>

export default Header

const styles = nav_container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    ...styling.navHeaderSize,
    backgroundColor: colors.black,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: DeviceInfo.hasNotch() === true ? '20@ms' : '20@ms',
    paddingHorizontal: '20@ms',
  },
```

You can call this in any screen and will work just as per your requirement.